# Store global settings in NSUserdefaults

Tags: swift

I want my App to have it's own settings (e.g. language settings). These I want to store in NSUserdefaults. What is the best way to read these settings and use them troughout the app?

At the moment I use global variables, that gets set in the Appdelegate with the function

```
func readNSUserDefaults() {

    let userdefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    pushFav          = userdefaults.valueForKey("pushFav")        == nil ? true : userdefaults.valueForKey("pushFav")!.boolValue
    pushVerband      = userdefaults.valueForKey("pushVerband")    == nil ? true : userdefaults.valueForKey("pushVerband")!.boolValue
    standortAuto     = userdefaults.valueForKey("standortAuto")   == nil ? true : userdefaults.valueForKey("standortAuto")!.boolValue
    languageSetting  = userdefaults.stringForKey("language")      ?? "auto"
    if languageSetting == "auto" {
        let autoLanguages = userdefaults.valueForKey("AppleLanguages")
        if let autoLanguages = autoLanguages as? [String] {
            print (autoLanguages)
            if autoLanguages.count > 0 {
                language = autoLanguages[0]
            }
        } else {
            language = "en-US"
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever the settings are changed I update both the NSUserdefaults and the global variables. Is there a more elegant way to do this? Like with a signleton?

Comment: You should use NSUserDefaults method boolForKey

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to 1. Make an enum with all of your keys for the defaults you store and 2. Just query what you need out of the defaults system when and where you need it. Forget updating and reading global values or creating a singleton as both are unnecessary bloat to your project.

```
// Make this available globally to your project
// This will ensure your keys are always correct.
enum DefaultsKeys: String {
    case PushFav
    case PushVerband
    case StandortAuto
    case Language
}

// Use this in your project where you need to use the default values
// It is only two lines, and will always be consistent.
let userdefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let pushFav = userdefaults.boolForKey(DefaultsKeys.PushFav.rawValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

The getter setters in swift would help u out here...
Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html

```
var setting1:String {
    get {
        if let setting1 = userDefaults.valueForKey("setting1") as? String {
            return setting1
        } else {
    //set the value for the default settings 1
            let setting1 = "Value"
            userDefaults.setObject(setting1, forKey: "setting1")
            userDefaults.synchronize()
            return setting1
        }
    }
    set {
        userDefaults.setObject(newValue, forKey: "setting1")
        userDefaults.synchronize()
    }
}
```

Something of this sorts should help...hopefully!